# linux ffmpeg 7:4.1.3-1 build don't support RTMPS

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I go to https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/ffmpeg and download `ffmpeg_3.2.14.orig.tar.xz`, and I configure&make&make install and finally I successfully build ffmpeg.

But when I use RTMPS protocol, such as:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i /root/video/xxx.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv "rtmps://xxx/xxx/xxx"
```

Then an error occur:

> ... Protocol not found

But in https://ffmpeg.org/general.html , it says that ffmpeg now support RTMPS.

So is something I missing when I build ffmpeg?

Comment: What does `ffmpeg -buildconf` say?

Comment: @Gyan it was `--disable-yasm` before, and I add `--enable-openssl` and it support rtmps now

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything. ffmpeg uses the `librtsp` module to handle all forms of the RTMP request like RTMPS. The problem is that `librtsp` is reliant on an SSL/TLS module or service to do the encryption – but there is no support for that in the standard ffmpeg builds.

Hence, RTMPS requests stall out when used. I am still researching the correct SSL/TLS modules to use. The bottom line is that it looks like we will just have to compile our own ffmpeg that includes the use of perhaps OpenSSL.

Added in edit: Some things I've said here are not quite true. See my comment below.

Comment: finally, I try ./configure --enable-openssl and successfully build rtmps-supported ffmpeg. Thanks

Comment: ffmpeg has native support for rtmp(s). External lib (librtmp) can be used but is not necessary.

Comment: I found that out in my journey for how to support rtmps directly with ffmpeg. I found that the latter builds have built into them support for the rtmps command but you still have to support it with an ssl/tls encryption module. I find that the consensus is to use the internal rtmp provided in the ffmpeg source package and build it using gnutls as the encryption module.  When rtmps is specified, then the internal rtmp module will activate the ssl/tls protocals of the ssl/ tls module that is provided. 
My thanks to JEEB on the ffmpeg Freenode IRC channel for this insite.

Comment: omg thaks for this.  My windows build of ffmpeg was stalling out with my rtmps code, and I was struggling to figure out how I broke my code so badly.   After I saw this I grabbed a different ffmpeg build and that worked.  Thought I was going out of my mind.